# Why is makefile not calling this function?

Tags: c, makefile, clang

I am trying to compile all the files with a .c extension into an object folder and then create an executable. However, the Makefile I am using is not registering the source files at all. Instead it is going ahead and calling the command to create the executable with object files that do not exist.

Here is the Makefile:

```
CC = clang

SOURCE_DIR = src
OBJECT_DIR = objects
EXECUTABLE = main

SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c, $(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    rm objects/*.o main

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: all $(OBJECTS)
```

And here is the output:

```
me@hostname:~/parent_dir$ make
clang objects/main.o objects/test.o -o main
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'objects/main.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'objects/test.o'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [Makefile:11: all] Error 1
```

And here is the file structure:

```
parent_dir:
   \ objects (empty):
   \ src:
      - main.c
      - test.c
   - Makefile
```

Comment: Is `test.c` in `src`?  You don't show it in the file structure but make sees it.

Comment: yeah sorry - forgot to add that

Comment: Why do you have `$(OBJECTS)` listed as `PHONY` targets?

Comment: Run make like this: `make --debug=v`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
.PHONY: all $(OBJECTS)
```

with:

```
.PHONY: all
```

The object files are not [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)
and telling `make` they are phony tells it that no such files have to exist.

Comment: thanks, man. I didn't understand phony targets and was just combining some tutorials.

Comment: The reason is slightly different than suggested above.  The reason it doesn't work if you declare them phony is _implicit rule search (see Implicit Rules) is skipped for .PHONY targets._ (see GNU make manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html )  That means PHONY targets will never use pattern rules to try to create them.  If there were explicit rules for these objects instead of a pattern rule, they would be created even if they were PHONY.  In fact, every time you run `make` they would be created, since that's what PHONY means.